# how to vary user input in a mathematical calculation leading to change in results

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day! please I want to build a program that automates the process of calculation in a bill. In this calculation, when the user inputs the total price of the bill, automatically the price of different components should be calculated using percentages (each component has its own percentage of the total price). I wrote the code below that prompts the user for a total amount and how the percentages is to be shared to different components

```
d=float(input('input amount: '))
calc = {}
while True:
        item = input("input component(enter 'stop' to quit): ")
        if item == 'stop':
            break
else:
   percentage = float(input('input percentage of price: '))
   price = (percentage / 100) * d
   calc[item] = price
for k, v in calc.items():
        print(k, v)
```

the results of the program is:

```
input amount: 100
input component(enter 'stop' to quit): solar panel
input percentage of price: 20
input component(enter 'stop' to quit): battery
input percentage of price: 40
input component(enter 'stop' to quit): inverter
input percentage of price: 40
input component(enter 'stop' to quit): stop
solar panel 20.0
battery 40.0
inverter 40.0
```

As you can see the code prompts the user for the total amount, components of the bill, and their percentages. The percentages then determine how much of the total amount is going to each components. my problem is after all this has been done, I want the user to be able to change the total amount as much as he/she wants while maintaining the already existing percentages the user chose for each component. so for example in the above results of my code I want the user to be able to change the 'input amount' to 200, 350, 10,000 and so on and these values will be shared to the different components according to the already existing percentages issued to them by the user. Please how can I do this?
I hope this makes sense, I am still a beginner at python, thanks.

Comment: The `else:` statement needs to be indented so it's connected to `if`, not `while`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do it like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Need Python3.8+


def show_result(components, amount):
    for k, v in components.items():
        print(k, v / 100 * amount)


def game():
    d = float(input('input amount: '))
    components = {}
    while True:
        if (item := input("input component(enter 'stop' to quit): ")) == 'stop':
            break
        components[item] = float(input('input percentage of price: '))
    show_result(components, d)

    while True:
        if (amount := input("\ninput amount(enter 'exit' to quit): ")) == 'exit':
            break
        show_result(components, float(amount))


def main():
    game()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```